# Unable to access private repositoryusing github API

Tags: github, oauth, access-token, github-api, private-repository

I'm unable to pull issues of private repository under my account.

I've created personal access token with repo permissions.

Using this command to fetch issues :

`curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues -H "Authorization: token {personal-access-token}"`
But getting error :

**{
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#list-repository-issues"
}**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check for the repository under the organization account; then you must use:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{organization}/{repo}/issues
```

The full command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token {personal-access-token}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/{organization}/{repo}/issues
```